# Unable to bring value from json to hyperlink in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

here i want to get the hyperlink value ( in my case data in json object) ie 6 and 7 in hyperlink format. I have converted the cell template but i m not able to get the value of json in the grid. i get "link" as text not its value

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head lang="en">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        </body>
    </html>var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

main.js
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, link: 6},
                         {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, link: 7},
                         ];
        $scope.gridOptions = { 
          data: 'myData', 
          columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' },
                     { field: 'age', displayName: 'Age' },
                     { field: 'link', displayName: 'Link',
                      cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a href="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}">link</a></div>'
                     }]
        };
    });
```

Comment: That is so because you have the text "link" hardcoded in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a name to your links:

```
  $scope.myData = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    age: 50,
    link: "http://www.google.com",
    linkname: "Google"
  }, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    age: 43,
    link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
    linkname: "Help me!"
  }, ];
```

Then use this celltemplate:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a target="_blank" href="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}">{{row.entity.linkname}}</a></div>'
```

Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5FlBSsdGnJw4kYhrF8r?p=preview) with the full code

Or, if you can not add a field to your json try this template:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a target="_blank" href="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}">{{row.entity.link}}</a></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to this:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a href="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}">{{ col.link }}</a></div>
```

Comment: i tried this but couldnot get the value in cell. Still getting empty cell @Mathew Berg